# How to Dynamically remove a item in selected list when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: apex, visualforce

I Have two visualforce page calling same controller.

Visualforce 1 -

```
 <apex:page controller="Contact_Checkbox_Class2" >

   <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Enter Contact Name"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!cname2}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!getdetails2}" />
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

      </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

    <apex:include pageName="MultiselectContact2" rendered="{!Rendered2}" />
</apex:page>
```

Visualforce 2-

```
<apex:page controller="Contact_Checkbox_Class2" tabStyle="Contact" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >  


        <apex:pageBlockSection Title="List of Available Contact" >
            <apex:dataTable value="{!Contact2}" var="a" columnswidth="50px,50px" cellpadding="6" border="1">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:outputLabel >Name </apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox >
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!GetSelected2}" onsubmit="checkAll(this)" rerender="Selected_PBS"/>
                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected2}" id="checkedone">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!GetSelected2}" rerender="Selected_PBS"/></apex:inputCheckbox>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headervalue="Contact Name" value="{!a.acc2.Name}" />
                <apex:column headervalue="Email" value="{!a.acc2.Email}" />
                <apex:column headervalue="Phone" value="{!a.acc2.Phone}" />
            </apex:dataTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Selected Contact" id="Selected_PBS">
            <apex:dataTable value="{!SelectedContact2}" var="s" columnswidth="50px,50px" cellpadding="4" border="1">
                <apex:column headervalue="Contact Name" value="{!s.Name}" />
                <apex:column headervalue="Email" value="{!s.Email}" />
                <apex:column headervalue="Phone" value="{!s.Phone}" />
            </apex:dataTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
        <apex:commandButton value="Email Wizard" action="{!SendTestEmailRedirect2}" />
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>    
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
<script>
    function checkAll(cb)
    {
        var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
        {
            if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
            inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Apex controller -

```
public class Contact_Checkbox_Class2 {

public PageReference SendTestEmailRedirect2() {
    return null;
}


public String cname2{set;get;}
public list<Contact> result2{set;get;}  


public  Integer t2=0; 


List<contactwrapper2> contactList2 = new List<contactwrapper2>();
List<contact> selectedcontact2 = new List<Contact>();
Boolean render2=false;


public PageReference getdetails2(){
   // selectedcontact.clear();
   contactList2.clear();
   String s3 ='SELECT Id,Name,Email,Phone FROM contact WHERE Name LIKE \'%' + cname2 + '%\'';
   result2 = database.query(s3);
   if(render2==false){
           render2=true;
       }          
   return null;          
}

public boolean getRendered2(){return render2;}

public List<contactwrapper2> getcontact2(){
    for(contact a : result2)
    contactList2.add(new contactwrapper2(a));
    return contactList2;
}


public PageReference getSelected2()
{

    for(contactwrapper2 accwrapper : contactList2)
    {
        for(integer i=0;i<selectedcontact2.size();i++)
        {
        if (selectedcontact2[i]==accwrapper.acc2){
        t2=1;   

        }
        }     

        if(accwrapper.selected2 == true && t2!=1){
         selectedcontact2.add(accwrapper.acc2);
        }


        t2=0;
    }  
   t2=0;


   return null;
}

public List<contact> GetSelectedcontact2()
{
    if(selectedcontact2.size()>0)
    return selectedcontact2;
    else{

    return null;
    } 
}   

public class contactwrapper2
{
    public contact acc2{get; set;}
    public Boolean selected2 {get; set;}
    public contactwrapper2(contact a)
    {
        acc2 = a;
        selected2 = false;
    }
}
}
```

I want to implemented when the selected contact in the contactlist get unchecked it should get removed from selectedlist.

PLease help.. all the code i tried not working. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this change where the ID values to remove are found and then those are used to remove the items from the other list:

```
public PageReference getSelected2()
{
    Set<Id> idsToRemove = new Set<Id>();
    for (contactwrapper2 sc : contactList2)
    {
        if (!sc.selected2) ids.add(idsToRemove.acc2.Id);
    }
    for (Integer i = selectedcontact2.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (idsToRemove.contains(selectedcontact2[i].Id)) selectedcontact2.remove(i);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Before going much further you should also clean up the names used in the code as they add confusion in the code.

**PS**

Code above made some bad assumptions about the rest of the controller. If I was writing the controller it would look like this:

```
public class MyController {

    public class ContactWrapper {
        public Contact sob {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public ContactWrapper(Contact sob) {
            this.sob = sob;
            this.selected = false;
        }
    }

    public String contactName {set; get;}
    public List<ContactWrapper> selectableContacts {get; private set;}
    public List<Contact> selectedContacts {get; private set;}

    public MyController() {
        selectableContacts = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
    }

    // Call from apex:commandButton
    public PageReference search() {
        selectableContacts.clear();
        String likeTerm = '%' + contactName + '%';
        for (Contact c : [
                select Id, Name, Email, Phone
                from Contact
                where Name like :likeTerm
                order by Name
                ]) {
            selectableContacts.add(new ContactWrapper(c));
        }
        if (selectableContacts.size() > 0) {
            return Page.SecondPageName;
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
                    ApexPages.Severity.INFO,
                    'No matches, try again'
                    ));
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Call from apex:actionSupport
    public PageReference selectionChanged() {
        selectedContacts.clear();
        for (ContactWrapper cw : selectableContacts) {
            if (cw.selected) selectedContacts.add(cw.sob);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. . it is removing selected contacts when they are selected too.

Comment: @Rachit I hadn't followed your code through enough; see the solution posted in the PS.

Comment: Thanks keith.. for your reply. But i already solved the issue. I will take a note of your solution and test it along with my reset of code. Anyway thanks.